# Undetected external monitor, refresh rate stuck with single resolution

Tags: grub2, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

Freshly installed Lunar on my `Legion 5i Pro Gen 7 (16" Intel) (12700h + 3070ti)` laptop.
Plugged external monitor is not even showing in the settings.
Resolution choice is stuck on 2560 * 1600 with a refresh rate which is also locked at 93Hz (max is 165hz)

Using : `nvidia-driver-535`, `x11` and kernel version `6.2.0-24-generic`.

xrandr :

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 2560 x 1600, current 2560 x 1600, maximum 2560 x 1600
default connected primary 2560x1600+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   2560x1600     93.00*
```

I tried editing `/etc/default/grub` with `GRUB_GFXMODE=2560x1600` and `update-grub` to fix `xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default` but no effects. Also tried to boot onto grub menu then press C for command line and run `vbeinfo` and `videoinfo` but getting an error about the command not being able to run with secure boot.

Is there a way to get the supported resolutions/refresh rates in the settings and how do I get my external monitor to be recognized and displayed ?

Thanks in advance

`dmesg` : https://pastebin.com/4iChrxXC

```
sudo dmesg | grep -iF error

[    0.010384] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs within socket(s), fixing all errors
[    0.936865] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
[    1.970400] EDAC igen6 MC1: HANDLING IBECC MEMORY ERROR
[    1.970404] EDAC igen6 MC0: HANDLING IBECC MEMORY ERROR
[    4.264887] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_TZ.ETMD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[    4.264921] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.IETM._OSC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
[   13.375194] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC0._Q37.PNOT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)
[   13.375232] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC0._Q37 due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)

sudo nvidia-xconfig        

Using X configuration file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf".

VALIDATION ERROR: Data incomplete in file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.
                  Device section "Device0" must have a Driver line.


ERROR: Unable to find any GPUs in the system.

Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.nvidia-xconfig-original'
Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup'
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'

sudo nvidia-settings

ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


(nvidia-settings:93160): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 19:15:32.657: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

** (nvidia-settings:93160): CRITICAL **: 19:15:32.658: ctk_powermode_new: assertion '(ctrl_target != NULL) && (ctrl_target->h != NULL)' failed

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file or the X server is not accessible. This file should have been installed along with this driver at /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The application profiles will
       continue to work, but values cannot be prepopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text. Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.

** Message: 19:15:32.682: PRIME: Requires offloading
** Message: 19:15:32.682: PRIME: is it supported? yes
** Message: 19:15:32.700: PRIME: Usage: /usr/bin/prime-select nvidia|intel|on-demand|query
** Message: 19:15:32.700: PRIME: on-demand mode: "1"
** Message: 19:15:32.700: PRIME: is "on-demand" mode supported? yes
```

Comment: Just confirming the monitor works with the same cables on another device or OS? I've seen this kind of issue when I had a bad/incompatible HDMI cable - using another means of connecting the display may help. Any relevant messages in `dmesg` that may help?

Comment: Yes cables are working correctly, just not with this laptop (windows in dual boot detects display)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by randomly tweaking my system because of slow startup

`systemd-analyze blame` gave me a time of 20s for `plymouth-quit-wait.service`

```
#old line
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset noplymouth"
#new line
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="fsck.mode=skip quiet"
```

Surprisingly after a quicker boot, my system had all the resolutions and refresh rates my screen supported.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the configuration file that was produced with nvidia-xconfig
Since I do not know your configuration, I would share mine: (generated by `nvidia-xconfig` )

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 470.86

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    ...your own stuff here


EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    Option "NoLogo" "1"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
    Option         "COMPOSITE" "Enable"
EndSection

 
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier          "Keyboard Defaults"
    MatchIsKeyboard        "yes"
    Option              "XkbOptions" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
EndSection
```

Currently that file resides in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-mhwd.conf. If the generated file lies somwhere else, you could link it with `ln -s`

**Note that I removed part of my input section due to a very special config (old hardware)**

Comment: I updated the post with the outputs

Comment: ** VALIDATION ERROR: Data incomplete in file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.
                  Device section "Device0" must have a Driver line.
** - You need to fix that -due to this error the driver will not be loaded